# VoIP SIP partial number dialing

Tags: session, request, sip, voip

When using an old style analogue or ISDN telephone, the dialing of a number is not closed to the end. There is no signal the number is complete and finished. However, adapters and such enable old phones for VoIP using SIP.

As I understand, the SIP request headers contain the whole client address or number.

How then is a SIP session established without knowing if the dialed number is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIP (per se) doesn't say anything about when calls are made or dialing, that's entirely up to the device or program.  Most ATAs act like traditional POTS phones connected to a switch, and dial off a completed dial-plan entry that matched (like 1-212-345-6789 or 911 or 411), or when a time since the last digit has elapsed (though most of those will end up forwarded to the "you've dialed an invalid number, please try again" message or beeps).  True IP phones often function closer to a cellphone (or cordless phone) model, with a "call" or "dial" button.

In many devices the dial-plan is programmable, sometimes by the user, other times (more often) by the service provider (Vonage, etc), in a few by either party.

Depending on the dial-plan, it may do more or less validation of the number being dialed in the matching (like checking for valid area-code digits or not, etc).

Comment: I was trying to read your answer pretending not to know what a "dial plan" was, and failed :-) The "dial plan" in this context is a description of all valid phone numbers. Usually by way of simple patterns. So your ATA knows when you are dialing local, long distance or international, and how many digits each should be. And there's a timeout as well.

Comment: It seems at least at germany the dial plan is NO simple pattern, as some cities got longer numbers with time that interspersed the old ones. So there would be no simple prefix to decide on the numbers length.

Answer (score 1):

by guessing. If there comes no additional digit within a certain number of seconds, the call will be made. Often you can speed up this by terminating your number with a `#` or similiar.

Comment: Is this delay adjustable in vanilla VoIP phones?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. I guess that it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

glglgl's guess is correct, a SIP device only initiates a call once it has acquired the full number it needs to use. SIP uses URIs in call requests which are very similar to email addresses and in the same manner that sending an email to a partial address is likely to fail initiating a call with a partial SIP URI is also likely to.

As to how SIP devices recognise when the user has completed the number it's normally done with a timeout, for example no more keys pressed within 10 seconds, or by the user pressing a "Send" key which as glglgl also alludes to will often be the # key on phones connected to an ATA. IP Phones typically have a "Send" or "Dial" button.

Some ATAs do allow you to adjust the timeout to detect when a user has completed dialling. I know the original Sipura ATAs (now owned by Cisco) allowed the delay to be configured in their internal dialplan.